# Как сделать у flexbox max-height 100% c прокручиванием?

Tags: css, html5, flexbox

Есть у меня такой вот код

```css
MAIN {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.text-block-1 {
  background-color: #43e8e5;
}

.text-block-2 {
  background-color: #43e846;
}

.text-block-3 {
  background-color: #e0e843;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.text-block-4 {
  background-color: #e87a43;
}

.text-block-5 {
  background-color: #dcaae6;
}

.text-block-6 {
  background-color: #5e4f61;
}

.text-block-7 {
  background-color: #6255b5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
  <div class="container flex-grow-1 d-flex mt-2">
    <div class="row flex-grow-1">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-xxl-6 box">
        <div class="text-center fw-bold text-block-1">
          <span>
                        Заголовок
                    </span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-block-2">
          Блок 1
        </div>
        <div class="text-block-3">
          <div class="text-block-4"><span>суб блок 2</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-5"><span>суб блок 3</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>


        </div>
        <div class="text-block-7">
          Блок прижатый к самому низу
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Как вы можете увидеть *.text-block-3* растянут на всю высоту родителя за вычетом футера этого родителя. В принципе это поведение правильно и является нужным мне, однако я столкнулся с такой проблемой, если контента больше чем может вместить в себя по вертикале блок, то он начинается растягиваться в низ. А я хочу что бы он прокскроливался по высоте.
Логика подсказывает что надо сделать что то вроде max-height высота на которую растянут блок, однако max-height: 100% не будет работать для flex.
В ходе целого дня экспериментов я добился нужного эффекта только задав фиксированную высоту блока в пикселях  [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/oufth0aw/): однако как вы понимаете такой подход не правельный, может кто ни будь подсказать что я должен сделать что бы добиться такова же эфекта только без указания явного размера? что бы блок не растягивался больше чем он щас есть?

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов - использование viewport height `vh` + `calc`

Пример

```css
MAIN {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.text-block-1 {
  background-color: #43e8e5;
}

.text-block-2 {
  background-color: #43e846;
}

.text-block-3 {
  background-color: #e0e843;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.text-block-4 {
  background-color: #e87a43;
}

.text-block-5 {
  background-color: #dcaae6;
}

.text-block-6 {
  background-color: #5e4f61;
}

.text-block-7 {
  background-color: #6255b5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<main class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
  <div class="container flex-grow-1 d-flex mt-2">
    <div class="row flex-grow-1">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-xxl-6 box">
        <div class="text-center fw-bold text-block-1">
          <span>
                        Заголовок
                    </span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-block-2">
          Блок 1
        </div>
        <div class="text-block-3">
          <div class="text-block-4"><span>суб блок 2</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-5"><span>суб блок 3</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
          <div class="text-block-6"><span>суб блок 4</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-block-7">
          Блок прижатый к самому низу
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Не не то, он так считает размер всего экрана, а если сверху есть еще блоки то отступ будет больше чем надо. Надо считать именно до низа родительского блока